# Hyperlink in WebView conflicts with scroll indicator in SfListView

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, webview, hyperlink, syncfusion

We are currently developing a mobile app using Xamarin Forms app. In the solution, we have used 4.7.0.1260 version of Xamarin.Forms. However, with this version we are facing an issue of scrolling indicator in SfListView for Android device, however it is working completely fine in iOS device.

After investigating this issue, we came across one blog which asked to upgrade the Xamarin.Forms version. Hence, we have upgraded the Xamarin.Forms version to 4.8.0.1687. After doing this change, the scrolling indicator was visible even in Android devices, but then we came across another issue that the hyperlinks in WebView are not clickable anymore in Android devices. In addition to this, we are using Android native web view with custom renderer. We are using ShouldOverrideUrlLoading method to open hyperlink URL in relevant app or browser.

Sample Hyperlink:

`<a href=\"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TxbE79-1OSI\" target=\"_blank\">African Wildlife</a>`

So, it seems that there is a conflict between hyperlink in WebView and scroll indicator in SfListView in different versions of Xamarin.Forms.

Is there version that includes both the functionalities as working in the same Xamarin.Forms version?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**#Regarding Scrollbar visibility**

You can show/hide the ScrollBar in using [SfListView.IsScrollBarVisible](https://help.syncfusion.com/cr/xamarin/Syncfusion.ListView.XForms.SfListView.html#Syncfusion_ListView_XForms_SfListView_IsScrollBarVisible) API. Please refer the following documentation for the same,

https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/listview/scrolling#scrollbar-visibility

**#Regarding the hyperlinks in WebView is not clickable anymore in Android devices**

Unable to reproduce the issue and you can find the tested sample from the following link,

[Sample](https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/3056991208564463)

Please revert with issue reproducing sample to check further.